# check to see if 3 values in array are consecutive?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, int

I have an array, which for example contains the values 123456, which obviously contains more than 3 consecutive values.

I want a method that will return true if the array contains at least 3 consecutive values in it, thanks in advance.

for example:

972834 - return true (234)

192645 - return true (456)

etc. etc..

update! :

i have an array in java, it takes in 6 integers.
for example nextTurn[], and it contains 8 4 2 5 6 5
at the moment it sorts the array - 2 4 5 5 6 8

how would i get it to return true if there are 3 consecutive numbers throughout the array?

ie so it will find 4 5 6

i would also like it to return the position of the integer in the array,
so for the original array 8 4 2 5 6 5

it will return, 2 4 5
or 2 5 6

thanks for all your help guys, appreciated

Comment: What language are you using? Also those don't look like arrays, more like strings (unless, unlikely, you're referring to `char *`)

Answer (score 3):

The most straight forward solution would be to simply loop through the items, and check against the next two items:

```
bool HasConsecutive(int[] a){
  for(int i = 0; i < a.Length - 2; i++) {
    if (a[i + 1] == a[i] + 1 && a[i + 2] == a[i] + 2) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Another solution is to loop through the items and count consecutive items:

```
bool HasConsecutive(int[] a){
  int cnt = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == a[i - 1] + 1) {
      cnt++;
      if (cnt == 3) return true;
    } else {
      cnt = 1;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Check out the examples shown in the question, the title is a bit misleading. It appears that they want to know if three consecutive numbers exist anywhere in the entire array, *not* whether they're in consecutive locations.

Comment: @LukeH: Hm... It seems that you are right. Then not only the title is misleading, but most of the question. Consecutive means that the numbers follow each other, numbers picked at random locations in the array are not consecutive.

Comment: I agree that the wording is very misleading, but the numbers themselves -- for example, 2, 3 and 4 -- *are* consecutive, they're just not in consecutive array locations.

Answer (score 1):

Should be tagged homework I'm assuming.

In pseudo code you are going to want something along the lines of

```
for int i = 0 to array.length - 2
    temp = array[i]
    if((array[i+1] == (temp + 1)) && (array[i+2] == (temp + 2)))
        return true
else return false
```

edit: This is assuming you have an array of ints. If it is a string, you are going to have to use something along the lines of charAt(position) and then convert the char to a decimal number, by subtracting '0' or using a parseInteger function

**Update on the misleading part**

To do this, I would create an array the same length of the string, for simplicities sake

```
int arr[array.length];
```

then loop through every item in the string array, while incrementing arr at the position the number falls at

(assuming a char array, single digit numbers)
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        arr[array[i] - '0']++;

then go through arr checking for three consecutive numbers

```
for( int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++ )
    if( arr[i] >= 1 && arr[i+1] >= 1 && arr[i+2] >= 1 )
        return true;

return false;
```

Comment: Check out the examples shown in the question, the title is a bit misleading. It appears that they want to know if three consecutive numbers exist anywhere in the entire array, *not* whether they're in consecutive locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = new hash table
for i in array
  if  i + 1 in h && i + 2 in h
    return i, i+1, i+2
  add i to h
return no-match
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's a solution.

```js
function checkConsecutiveExists(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (checkNumLast(arr, arr[i]) || checkNumMid(arr, arr[i]) || checkNumFirst(arr, arr[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


function checkNumLast(arr, num) {
  return arr.includes(num - 2) && arr.includes(num - 1);
}

function checkNumMid(arr, num) {
  return arr.includes(num - 1) && arr.includes(num + 1);
}

function checkNumFirst(arr, num) {
  return arr.includes(num + 1) && arr.includes(num + 2);
}

console.log(checkConsecutiveExists([9, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4]));
console.log(checkConsecutiveExists([1, 9, 2, 6, 4, 50]));
```

It's a brute force solution, so not the most optimal.